# Komodo Edit disable autocomple

Tags: python, autocomplete, komodo

I am using Komodo Edit 8 and its autocomplete feature is totally annoying.
As soon as I type **"for i"** , it autofills in this:

```
for i in range:
  code
```

Now i have to delete it manually to continue typing. I tried to turn off **"Enable automatic autocomplete and calltips triggering when you type"** from **Edit>Prefrence>Code Intelligence** but the problem persists.

What's the real way to turn it off?

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

> Edit > Preferences > Smart Editing > Auto-Abbreviation > **Uncheck** "Enable Auto-Abbreviation with Trigger Characters"

Comment: Thank you, I spent too much time searching for this option, the JavaScript auto complete was too annoying

Comment: in 8.5 "smart editing" is under "editor" within your preferences.

Comment: I bet the developers of Komodo Edit don't use this feature.  It's literally disgusting.

Answer (score 2):

The option "Enable automatic autocomplete and calltips triggering when you type" refers to the tooltips the pop up for example when calling a function in a module. Type "math.sq" and it'll suggest the rest of the text for the sqrt function.

To turn off the autocomplete you're referring to uncheck "Enable Auto-Abbreviation with Trigger Characters" under Edit > Preferences > Smart Editing > Auto-Abbreviation.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=FLbFCkNHLI4 for an overview.

Answer (score 1):

on mac it's under Preference -> Editor -> Smart Editing -> Auto-Abbreviations